# GET request with nested objects in @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-web

Is it possible to create a `GET` webservice in spring and using *nested properties* in the query? Like `search.limitResults` in the following example:

```
localhost:8080/firstname=test&search.limitResults=10
```

You get the idea. Can this be achieved?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   private String test(RestParams p) {

   }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestParams {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    //is that possible to nest?
    private Search search;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Search {
   private int limitResults;
   //some more
}
```

Comment: Did you try using this with @RequestParam in your parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: it just **works** this way! Nested properties can be accessed using the dot accessor, like `search.limitResults`.